# Opening Excel File by ClosedXML.dll is showing error "Excel found unreadable content"

Tags: c#, import-from-excel, closedxml

Hi I have created an excel file using ClosedXML.dll and when I am going to open that file, it showing "Excel found unreadable content" message. My file content has swedish text. I don't know what is the root cause? Is there any way to set language? How to remove that warning please help me. Here is the code snap.

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);  //dt is DataTable

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+fileName+".xlsx");
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        MyMemoryStream.Capacity = (int)MyMemoryStream.Length;
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After lot of stuff I have found a solution from msdn blog site. That is

```
Response.Flush();
Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

Even I don't know the inner works of SuppressContent property, but it really works for me. It may remove some styling of my excel sheet and reducing the size of my file. And also I have removed Response.End() as it was throwing Thread Abort Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to set the position of the stream to 0.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
document.SaveAs(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
stream.Close();
```